# Why is the html file of the http-response in this code incomplete?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get some data from a website (https://www.evaschulze-aufgabenpool.de/index.php/s/smwP6ygck2SXRtF) by using python and the modules "requests" and "BeautifulSoup" but it seems like I get an incomplete html file as a response. E.g. the table tag inside the html file I get as response with my code lacks of lines compared to the original html file when inspecting it with my browser. So my Question is: What is the reason for this and how can I solve this problem?

Here's the code I used to get the data inside the table tag:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

source = requests.get("https://www.evaschulze-aufgabenpool.de/index.php/s/smwP6ygck2SXRtF").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "html.parser")
for table in soup.find_all("table"):
    print(table)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What happens?**

Content of table is generated dynamically and is not included in the response of your request. You have to wait until page/content is loaded.

**What you can do is go with selenium**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

url = "https://www.evaschulze-aufgabenpool.de/index.php/s/smwP6ygck2SXRtF"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get(url)
#driver.implicitly_wait(10) 
sleep(3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"lxml")

for table in soup.find_all("table"):
    print(table)

driver.close()
```